# how can solve problem with IndexError in linux

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Today when I run my code in server computer which is Linux I faced nonsense error while when I run this code in my PC which is windows I don't get error. Basically I call my data via dataframe and after indexing I applied on dataframe !

```
IndexError: index 40 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 40
```

My data size is 40x1440.

What's the reason?
[image: img]

**Update**

- Pandas version is 0.24.1 in linux
- Python version is 3.6.8  in linux
- Pandas version in 0.23.4 in Win 7
- Python version in 3.6.6  in Win 7

My code is following:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("Train.csv", header=None)
print(df.shape)
#(40, 1440)

index = [i for i in list(range(1440)) if i%3!=2]
#print(index)

Y_train = df[index]
df = df.values
```

I have uploaded a formatted [csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YgbhwIgnW42bwOnaxM2e_JHwsf3Q9O2_/view?usp=sharing) dataset.

Comment: Is there same pandas version?

Comment: Try using index 39, to see if it is zero indexed.

Comment: @jezrael Versions are not same as it can be seen it **update**

Comment: @MegaEmailman it crossed to my min and I `print(index)` and `0` it's taken as index as it can be seen in picture! but even it's the case why I don't get this error in win 7?

Comment: python lists are 0 indexed, as is your dataframe. So the last index is index 39, hence 40 being an indexerror

Comment: @Craicerjack that's right but why I get this error in just Linux?

Answer (score 0):

as @Jezreal pointed I checked the versions in both system and I've installed same Pandas version by `pip install pandas==0.23.4` in linux and problem resolved surprisingly !! but It's obvious that python lists start index from `0` but why it shows `IndexError` in different version differently is mysterious!